# Getting Adapter information of BaseAdapter Before Deletion

Tags: android

I have a CustomBase adapter with a button attached to it,when I click on the button the row is to be deleted, which is working perfectly fine, but my problem is, that data which is populated in my adapter is from a remote server, I want to be getting the information contained by the adapter before deleting it and giving it to my MainActivity, in my case, I would like to be getting the title before the view is removed and sending it to the server, telling it to delete it from storage, the big issue is all code to do with the button is in my baseAdapter class, I do not know if I can give my MainActivity the data before the row is Deleted, I cannot think of a way of achieving that, if anyone has an idea please share, below is my Base Adapter.

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ViewHolder holder;
public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {






    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecartitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final ImageButton delete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.postCommentBox);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                listData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        delete.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(newsItem.getTitle());



    return convertView;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
   int position;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a ListFragment? If you do, check 
[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)) out.

If you do not, make your activity implement an *interface* e.g. `HandleDeletion` with a method e.g. `handleTitle(String title)`. In your clickListener cast the context object to `HandleDeletion` and call the method `handleTitle(String title)` on it. This is a so called callback.

[EDIT]
Example:

```
public interface HandleDeletion {
    handleTitle(String title);
}

public class MyActivity implements HandleDeletion {
    ...
    handleTitle(String title) {
        //do whatever you want 
    }
    ...
}


public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ...

    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((HandleDeletion)context).handleTitle(listData.get(position).getTitle());
                listData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You, Let me try and formulate something out of this, but if you have an example please share